# Error: with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, pixellib

Program exit with error:
ValueError: Layer #389 (named "mrcnn_bbox_fc"), weight <tf.Variable 'mrcnn_bbox_fc/kernel:0' shape=(1024, 324) dtype=float32> has shape (1024, 324), but the saved weight has shape (1024, 8).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)


def detect():
    segment = instance_segmentation()
    segment.load_model("C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5")

    target_classes = segment.select_target_classes(person=True)

    result = segment.segmentImage(
        image_path="InputData\\bus.jpg",
        show_bboxes=True,
        segment_target_classes=target_classes,
        output_image_name="obus.jpg"
    )

    persons = len(result[0]["sources"])
    print(persons)


def main():
    detect()
```

I try to using tensorflow-gpu 2.8.0 with pixellib 0.7.1 and I get this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:616: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\main.py", line 27, in main
    detect()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\main.py", line 11, in detect
    segment.load_model("C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5")
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\__init__.py", line 65, in load_model
    self.model.load_weights(model_path, by_name= True)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\mask_rcnn.py", line 2110, in load_weights
    hdf5_format.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f, layers)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FaceDetectionSchoolProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 795, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
    str(weight_values[i].shape) + '.')
ValueError: Layer #389 (named "mrcnn_bbox_fc"), weight <tf.Variable 'mrcnn_bbox_fc/kernel:0' shape=(1024, 324) dtype=float32> has shape (1024, 324), but the saved weight has shape (1024, 8).
```

Comment: You mistake a warning for the error. The error is likely unrelated and is shown in the last line; or rather, your headline is misleading as it references the warning, not the error